# Is this mem::transmute::<&str, &'static str>(k) safe?

Tags: rust

I'm looking at [this code](https://github.com/KeenS/www-authenticate/blob/1b2427d5c8d062d1d26c18ebab69d228be8b621e/src/lib.rs) which is a very simple library with just one file and mostly tests, so it's short. There's a struct that I'm trying to understand:

```rust
pub struct ChallengeFields(HashMap<UniCase<CowStr>, (String, Quote)>);

struct CowStr(Cow<'static, str>);
```

There's a line where it does

```rust
pub fn get(&self, k: &str) -> Option<&String> {
    self.0
        .get(&UniCase(CowStr(Cow::Borrowed(unsafe {
            mem::transmute::<&str, &'static str>(k)
        }))))
        .map(|&(ref s, _)| s)
}
```

I'm annoyed by this `unsafe` operation. I think `CowStr` is a `Cow` with `'static` lifetime otherwise it'd be hard or impossible to store `str`s inside the map. Because of that, when I try to get something inside this map, the `str` in question has to have `'static` lifetime. This is the reason for the `transmute`, right? If so, why simply not use `String`, so we can get rid of lifetimes and thus `transmute`? I don't like `unsafe`, and reading about `transmute` it looks very unsafe.

Also, I don't see why `Cow` is needed at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think `CowStr` is a `Cow` with `'static` lifetime otherwise it'd be hard or impossible to store strs inside the map.

Well yes and no, you can store `&'static str` inside a hashmap with no issue, the problem is that you can't store *both* `&'static str` and `String`.

> Am I rigth? If so, why simply not use String, so we can get rid of lifetimes and thus transmute?

I assume that is an optimisation: with `String` you'd have to create an allocation every time you want to insert a challenge in the map, but if the overwhelming majority of challenge names would be `Digest` and `Basic` then that's a waste of time (and memory but mostly time), but at the same time you'd have to support `String` for custom auth schemes.

Now maybe in the grand scheme of things this is not an optimisation which actually matter and it'd be better off not doing that, I couldn't tell you.

> I don't like unsafe, and reading about transmute it looks very unsafe.

It's a debatable thing to do, but in this case it's "safe", in the sense that the reference is valid for the entirety of the `HashMap::get` call and we know that that call doesn't keep the reference alive (it's reliance on an implementation detail which is a bit risky, but the odds that that would change are basically nil as it wouldn't make much sense).

Extending lifetimes is not in-and-of-itself UB (the `mem::transmute` documentation literally provides an example doing that), but requires care as you must avoid it causing UBs (the most likely being a dangling reference).

Comment: Ain't I creating an allocation everytime I insert a `CowStr` in the HashMap? I'm allocating the `CowStr`, even if it holds a reference, ain't I?

Comment: No, CowStr is just a newtype, it isn't anything "at runtime". Whereas a non-empty `String` triggers a heap allocation.

Comment: How can the HashMap allocate things that are not on the heap? For example `loop{my_hashmap.put(CowStr::Owned(something), 0)}`. Where are these `CowStr` stored?

Comment: Directly in the hashmap itself. Though `CowStr::Owned` implies a `String` which contains a heap-allocated buffer.

Comment: But doesn't the hashmap hold heap allocated memory?

Comment: Yes the hashmap does have its own buffer, but that's independent from the String's buffer, and amortized.

Comment: @Gatonito Perhaps it would be clearer if you imagine the "create an allocation" part of the answer as "create an _extra_ allocation". Yes, `HashMap::insert` allocates, but if it used `String` as key, it would require additional allocation for the owned string, which is avoidable and (in the code author's apparent opinion) unnecessary.